# What fallacy is "sports use it so it must be a good system"?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation

So basically the argument goes, "auto-promotion/relegation is an inherently flawed system because of x reasons." and the response is "well traditional sports have  used it for decades thus it's obviously the optimal system"

My initial assumption would be appeal to authority but i'm not too sure. Can anybody help clarify?

It suggests that it's generalization from induction but i believe it's slightly different. sports systems aren't infallible truths like the sun rising. 0

Comment: As for your edit: the whole point of the post linked is that 'the sun rising' is *not* an 'infallible truth'.

Comment: i know. What i'm saying is that the sun rising has always been true previously, whether or not it's true in the future is another matter. My point is, it's not similar to auto-promotion/relegation which has never been proven to be the optimal system, there's no evidence to suggest it's the optimal system right now and there's nothing that suggests is the best system in the future. I don't think the two examples are comparable. i'd love for clarification in case i'm missing something.

Comment: I think it's a combination Appeal to Authority, Appeal to Popularity (the commonality of use) and good ol' fashioned over-generalization. However, it seems that even Appeal to Popularity is an Appeal to an imagined authority that common use would have--and least in the person who thinks of it as authoritative. (And of course the generalization seems to shadow a sort of equivocation. "Good" for one case, provides a generalized idea of "good".)

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! I can see why you're asking this question, but generally putting a label to a fallacy doesn't help advance an argument against it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the argument.

First, let's change it to "well traditional sports have used it for decades thus it's obviously the optimal system *for traditional sports*". Well, that's not true. Traditional sports might be using a non-optimal system for whatever bizarre reasons. Or it might be a system that is known to be second best, but the transition to a different, better, system might be very hard. (Say there are two paths separated by barbed wire. You walk on one path. You clearly see the other path is better, but you can't switch because of the barbed wire).

Second, even if that system is optimal *for traditional sports*, that doesn't mean it's optimal elsewhere. I wouldn't say this is "generalisation from induction". That would be making the same observation in five similar situations and assuming that the same thing would happen in the sixth similar situation. Here the claim is that the same observation would happen in a different situation.